# How to show JSON response in single arrayList?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I am fetching some JSON data with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
    listdata.add(jsonobject.getString("ans1"));
    Log.e("listdata", String.valueOf(listdata));
}
```

output :

```
E/listdata: [true]
E/listdata: [false]
```

but I want to see something like this:

```
listdata: [true,false]
```

**Edit**: The JSON is structured like:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "id": 197,
    "ans1": "true",
    "ans2": null,
    "ans3": null,
    "ans4": null,
    ...
  }, {
    "id": 198,
    "ans1": "false",
    "ans2": null,
    "ans3": null,
    "ans4": null,
    ...
  }],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: post your json data..

Answer (score 1):

You can take `listdata` out of the `for` loop, such as:

```
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    listdata.add(jsonobject.getString("ans1"));
}  
Log.e("listdata", String.valueOf(listdata));
```

Comment: the problem now I am facing is that now it shows all the data inside the JSON array.@4castle

Comment: I only want to see a particular data "ans1",but it shows ans1,ans2,ans 3 and so on

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh That's unusual. Can you please post your JSON structure in your question? I don't see how that's possible unless `"ans1"` contains those values. The code quite explicitly is only accessing `ans1`.

Comment: @mins how can I get ans1 in an arrayList

Comment: I posted the JSON data @skadoosh

Comment: when the for loop is end ,the ans1 will add in the arrayList, you can use arrayList.get(index) get ans1@Shwetabh Singh